# Help ! Bosch 300 washer and dryer Under the sink hook up

Tags: plumbing, dryer, washing-machine, troubleshooting

I am finishing my Brooklyn apartment renovation and because of space decided to get the Bosch 300 stacked washer and ventless dryer.

My contractor hooked it all up for me under my kitchen sink, but was unfamiliar with the fact that the dryer also has a drain hose and has a water waste hose :( I found out only after water started to spew from the back of the machine.

Is there a way to hook up both the washer and dryer hose under my kitchen sink so I don't have to have a bucket for for when I want to use the dryer. Please see image of current set up under the kitchen sink - [image]

Comment: Easiest might be to cut the existing drain hose and put in 1-way valves in that hose and in the hose you'll add from the dryer, and use a T-fitting to go into the existing sink drain. The one-way valves are needed to prevent one appliance from pumping water into the other.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Wonderful thank you for the advice ! I will offer this as an option to the contractor see what he can come up with. Thank you again !